# Angular 4 - Input / Output Acessar evento do pai via Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

No Angular 4, como faço para acessar as funções do pai estando no filho ou as funções do filho estando no pai direto pelo *Typescript* ao invés de acessarem tradicionalmente via atributo de tag?

Comment: Desconheço outra forma, mas posso estar enganado por isso apenas deixo um comentário. Se explicar melhor o pretendido, talvés a solução seja outra, até porque não estou a ver o que não pode ser feito com `Input` ou `Output` que necessite de outra solução.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução parcial que encontrei foi Criar uma classe abstrata! Colocar nela alguns metodos abstratos (a medida que precise e sejam obrigatórios) e alimentar o construtor da classe abstrata (necessidades minhas). Feito isso, As telas (componentes) que precisei, passaram a extender dessa classe.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia Luiz Felipe, no Angular pode ser criado um service, assim que criado um service ele é um Injectable() e assim ele consegue ser passado nos construtores das novas classes em typescript.
Usando o CLI fica assim:

`ng g s shared/servico1 --flat` ( o flat para não criar uma pasta )

e no seu typescript novo pode passar ele no construtor e usar ele

```
construtor(private servi:servico1){

}
```